# ICSP Programming Protocol for PIC MCUs

Tags: microcontroller, pic, microchip

I have been using this site for many years now. It has been a huge help for me, so first of all thanks for everything. I almost always find the answers to my questions from previous posts, this is the first time I ask a question myself.

Ok, now to the main point. What is the actual protocol used to drive the PGD pin while sending the hex file to the target pic. I know that I could build a DIY ICSP Programmer from the countless projects found on the web but I truly want to understand the low level of this subject and build my own ICSP programmer for the sake of learning.

Some more details:
(Just to give you more info about what is on my mind)
The main idea is to use a pic with a USB module (say PIC18F2550) this pic will communicate with a software that sends the hex file to it. After PIC18F2550 stores this hex file (as raw data) in its memory it is going to send it to the target pic (the pic to be programmed) using the "ICSP protocol" (the thing I am looking for).

Comment: Ok, so I am still looking in the internet to find what I am looking for...I found this nice pdf but it is specific to some pics, and it is a bit old. I will keep searching hoping to find a more generalized document.

http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39644l.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link has the Programming Specification ( protocol ) for the chip family you want
[Microchip Programming Specification for PIC18F2550 Family](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiyyKr-n4PSAhUEsVQKHYIdBrgQFggaMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fww1.microchip.com%2Fdownloads%2Fen%2FDeviceDoc%2F39622L.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFF2KIQFSLaM12q5VwfVzTBL03qWw&sig2=Ek6fEcUqCrTLRtHceQLoRw)

Comment: Thanks :) the document does include what I need !